# Sanitizing user data for use in the page title without encoding to entities?

Tags: php, security, xss, code-injection, html-title

Obviously one of the main ways to protect against malicious code from users is to encode the data to `html entities`; however what about when using the data in the page `title` - as the page title doesn't convert the entities for display purposes and `&amp;` will display literally as `&amp;` instead of `&`.

I'm wondering what methods you can use to sanitize data for usage in the page titles? I have already run the `PHP` function `strip_tags` on the data, however unsure if this should be enough protection or should I be doing more?

Still encode but then do a decode afterwards for certain characters?

**Edit:** Firefox title bar screenshot below..

[image]

**My Input:**

```
<title>Testing 123 - &amp; testing</title>
```

**Source:**

```
<title>Testing 123 - &amp;amp; testing </title>
```

So looking at that, if I am to understand correctly it has double-encoded it, leaving me to believe that data inside the titles are automatically encoded and thus it is safe to insert unencoded data inside `<title>` tags?

I guess my only worry is - is this the case for all clients/browsers? ...or is `PHP` encoding it automatically?

Comment: That’s not true. When the [*title* element gets parsed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead), the [contents are treated as RCDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#generic-rcdata-element-parsing-algorithm), which [includes parsing of character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#rcdata-state).

Comment: @Gumbo Well I don't know what to tell ya - I tried a `&amp;` in the page title and in `Firefox` it shows literally as `&amp;` as I said; can't test in `Chrome` as they don't show the page title by default and not sure how to enable it.

Comment: In RCDATA you are also allowed to just write `&` if it is followed by certain whitespace (U+0009, U+000A, U+000C, or U+0020), another `&`, or a `<`.

Comment: @Gumbo I'm not sure what you're saying; that I don't need to sanitize the data?

Comment: Chrome does show the page title - are you looking in the address bar or elsewhere? Gumbo is correct.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Not in the Chrome I am using, they took it out to make more page space.

Comment: Add a Firefox screenshot and the output of the generated source.

Comment: It appears you (and/or the application) is double encoding output (hence `&amp;amp;`).